# Markov Chain for Conditional Entropy

Tags: discrete-mathematics, markov-chains, entropy

[image]

These informations are given. 
I need to prove that $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ is a Markov chain, then so is $Z \rightarrow Y \rightarrow X$ is a Markov chain

I tried to find some answers;

$Z \rightarrow Y \rightarrow X$

$H(Z) \ge H(Z:Y) \ge H(Z:X)$

$H(Z:Y,X) = H(Z:X)+H(Z:Y)$

$H(Z:Y) +H$

As you can see, I could not find any reasonable answer. By the way, this is not a homework. It is a question from my worksheet that is given to study for final examination. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can insert image by using the editor - you will have an image upload button (I just checked myself).

Comment: Yes, I realized that my points raised to 11 when I opened this topic. After 10 points we can add images as embedded. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Ah, I gave your question a +1 so maybe that is what pushed it over ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Markov chain definition, $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ if and only if

$$
\tag{1}
p(x,y,z)=p(x)p(y|x)p(z|y).
$$

By the standard chain rule, it also holds

$$
\tag{2}
p(x,y,z)=p(z)p(y|z)p(x|y,z).
$$

Now note that

$$
\begin{align}
p(x|y,z)&=\frac{p(x,y,z)}{p(y)p(z|y)}\\
&\stackrel{(a)}{=}\frac{p(x)p(y|x)p(z|y)}{p(y)p(z|y)}\\
&=\frac{p(x)p(y|x)}{p(y)}\\
&=p(x|y),\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

where $(a)$ follows from $(1)$. Substituting $(3)$ in $(2)$ results in

$$
p(x,y,z)=p(z)p(y|z)p(x|y),
$$

that is, it also holds $Z\rightarrow Y \rightarrow X$.

Another way to show this is to note that $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ if and only if

$$
\tag{4}
p(x,z|y)=p(x|y)p(z|y),
$$

i.e., the "first" and "last" variables are independent when conditioned on the "middle" variable. Since the "first" and "last" labels can be arbitrarily selected (either $X$, $Z$ or $Z$, $X$, respectively), it follows that condition $(4)$ also corresponds to $Z\rightarrow Y \rightarrow X$.

Comment: I understand your solution way. Thank you for your great explanations.